# How to remove de annoying square appearing above cells of vscode jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

How do I remove the annoying square appearing above cells of vscode jupyter notebook?[image]

Answer (score 2):

This panel is called "Cell toolbar". To hide it find in settings `Notebook: Cell Toolbar Location` and set all values to `hidden`.
[image: GIF of the process]